# jsp error message not displaying

Tags: java, spring, jsp

on JSP when I want to display error messages but when it returns to JSP page by

```
<form:errors path="arnNumber" cssClass="error" /></span>
```

it is giving me an exception

> org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException:
>   No message found under code 'ARN
>   number is
>   required.contactUsUtil.arnNumber' for
>   locale 'en_US'.

Comment: guess whether your question gives enough information ;)

Answer (score 0):

Literally translated, it just means that it cannot find any message associated with the following key

```
ARN number is required.contactUsUtil.arnNumber
```

in the message bundle as definied in the `messageSource` attribute of your `applicationContext.xml`.

The key looks suspicious :)

Answer (score 0):

define it under Application context

```
<bean id="responseMessageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3"/>
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:response_msg" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

define under resource folder ,it is easy

```
NO_SESSION=SESSION ERROR
NO_PHOTO=The photo with specified id couldn't find
SUCCESSFULL_CRATED_ALBUM=Album has created successfully
ASSIGNED_ALBUM_PHOTO=This photo assigned as your album photo.
SUCCESFULL_UPDATED_ALBUM=Album has updated successfully
SUCCESFULL_UPDATED_PHOTO=Photo has updated successfully
SUCCESFULL_CRATED_IMAGE_DIRECTORY=Image directories created successfully
```